# Jquery to find current bottom css value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element that is dynamically resized by code from a plugin.
its the custom scroll bar plug in located [Here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller).

So I'm using it for this little global chat thing I'm making, and basically, I'm polling the database to see if there are new messages, and if there are I'm updating the chat box and resizing.  THat all works fine.

Whats not working correctly, is that I have it set to auto scroll to the bottom on each update.  However this can be annoying if youre trying to look at things in the past at the top of the box.  So basically I'm thinking that I can check to see if the sliderule of the scroll bar is at the exact bottom then keep it there using the plugins bottom function.  But if its not at exactly 0 then just leave it where it is.

However, I'm unaware of a jquery function to that gets bottom on the fly like that.

When i try

```
alert($('.mCSB_container').css('bottom'));
```

its just saying : auto;

Anyone know of a function or way to calculate this?

Heres the html rendered by the plugin:

```
<div id="chat_messages_wrap" class="scrollbox mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1">
   <div class="mCustomScrollBox" id="mCSB_1" style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;">
      <div class="mCSB_container mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; top: 0px; ">                                              
         <div class="message_wrap" id="message_57">
            <span class="message_time">Mon Oct 08 2012 17:57:01</span>
            <div class="message_avatar_wrap"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="message_message_wrap">
               <span class="message_username">EyeptchsRLame</span>
               <p class="message_message">hey there</p>
            </div>
            <div class="message_divider"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mCSB_scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: none; ">
         <a class="mCSB_buttonUp" style="display:block; position:relative;"></a>
         <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; ">
               <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="position:relative;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
         </div>
         <a class="mCSB_buttonDown" style="display:block; position:relative;"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the bottom of an element by finding top value then adding the height

```
var obj = $('.mCSB_container');
var bottom = obj.position().top + obj.height();
```

Comment: hmmm, I think this has pointed me in the right direction.  I think I just need to figure out which element to get a size from now.  Sweet deal thanks.

Comment: The bottom css value is the distance between the bottom of the element and the bottom of its parent container. This answer will give you the distance between the elements bottom and the top of its parent container. Subtract from $('#container').outerHeight() to get the real bottom. Also, position() does not include padding, margin etc.

Answer (score 1):

As RTF suggested `position()` does not account for an element's padding, border, and margin.

You want to use `offset().top` instead to find the rendered element's `top` (aka the distance from the top of the document) and then add the total rendered height, using the `outerHeight()` jQuery function, **which includes the selected element's border, padding, and (if this function's parameter is set to `true`) margin.**

It will look something like this:

```
var container  = $('.mCSB_container'),
    top        = container.offset().top,
    height     = container.outerHeight(true),   // true to include margin
    bottom     = top + height + "px";           // add "px" so the browser has a unit to work with

console.log(bottom);
```